# java, when I cast int to short, which part of the int will be lost

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

java, when I cast int to short, which part of the int will be lost.

For example, when int i=32768, when I cast i to short, which part will be lost

As in java, int has 32 bits, and short only has 16 bits, when casting int to short, will the upper 16 bits be lost or the lower 16 bits?

Comment: Did you do any experimentation?

Answer (score 0):

short values are limited to -32768 to +32767, and Java only keeps the least significant 16 bits when casting to a short ([a narrowing primitive conversion, JLS 5.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3)).

**The upper 16 bits will be lost**

Example 5.1.3-2. Narrowing Primitive Conversions that lose information

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // A narrowing of int to short loses high bits:
        System.out.println("(short)0x12345678==0x" +
                           Integer.toHexString((short)0x12345678));
        // An int value too big for byte changes sign and magnitude:
        System.out.println("(byte)255==" + (byte)255);
        // A float value too big to fit gives largest int value:
        System.out.println("(int)1e20f==" + (int)1e20f);
        // A NaN converted to int yields zero:
        System.out.println("(int)NaN==" + (int)Float.NaN);
        // A double value too large for float yields infinity:
        System.out.println("(float)-1e100==" + (float)-1e100);
        // A double value too small for float underflows to zero:
        System.out.println("(float)1e-50==" + (float)1e-50);
    }
}
```